# Jquery drag and drop allow 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm having some trouble with jquery's drag and drop. I want to drag only 1 element from each 'ul'. So the result i want is a 'test' and a 'foo' in the red box. How can i keep track of what elements are in the red box?

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/9edge/CTpTr/

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill two seperate counters, one for each item type (And give your items classes to identify them).

Use the check() function to check your limits, and return true/false if reached or not, use the drop() function to update your counter.

```
$(function() {
    var limit = 1;
    var counter_test = 0;
    var counter_foo = 0;
    $("[id=drag]").draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $('#div1').droppable({
        accept: function(item) {
            if ($(item).hasClass('test')) {
                if (counter_test >= limit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (counter_foo >= limit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.hasClass('test')) {
                counter_test++;
            }
            else {
                counter_foo++;
            }
        }
    });
});
​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTpTr/19/)

[New Fiddle with IDs fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/CTpTr/20/)

Comment: Oh and, like Giovanni mentioned, you can't have the same ID multiple times on one page, please fix that, too.

Answer (score 1):

An idea of solution : http://jsfiddle.net/CTpTr/23/. You can only put 1 test element and 1 foo element, then you still can drag and drop but the drop won't be accepted in the droppable element.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle. 
The solution just slightly more complicated is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CTpTr/18/

As you can see, I removed the `drag` id from the `li` elements. An id is supposed to be unique  in a web page.
You can make those elements draggable with a selector another selector (`#lists li`).
Then I used two variables to keep track of the number of objects dragged and dropped in the red div.
The first one is "limits", the second one is "left".

```
var limits = { test: 1, foo: 1}, left = 2;
```

`limits` is the number of allowed elements from each list (based on the custom html5 data-dragtype attribute), `left` is the total number of elements allowed.
So, for example, if you would like to be able to add two elements of type "foo", and one of type "test", you could use

```
var limits = { test: 1, foo: 2}, left = 3;
```

Ore, if you would like to allow two "foo" and one "test", but with a total of two elements, 
you could use

```
var limits = { test: 1, foo: 2}, left = 2;
```

As you can see, it is a little more flexible than the version you asked for.

Every time an element is dropped, the drop event handler retrieves the dragged element with `drg.draggable`  (note the arguments `(e, drg)` of the function) and its type with `draggable.data('dragtype')`.

```
$(function() {
    var limits = { test: 1, foo: 1}, 
        left = 2;
    $("#lists li").draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $('#div1').droppable({
        drop: function(e, drg) {
            var draggable = $(drg.draggable), 
                dragtype = draggable.data('dragtype');
            left -=1;
            limits[dragtype] -= 1;
            if (left == 0) {
                $(this).droppable("disable");
                $('#lists li').draggable("disable");
            }
            if (limits[dragtype] == 0){
                $('li[data-dragtype=' + dragtype +']').draggable('disable');
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

So, if the limit is reached only for one type of `li`, you can disable the drag functionality of just the elements of that type with `$('li[data-dragtype=' + dragtype +']').draggable('disable')`.

One important thing to note is how easy it is to add another type of list.  For example, if you would want to add `li` elements of type "bar", you would add an `ul` element like this

```
<ul class="bar">
    <li data-dragtype="bar">bar1</li>
    <li data-dragtype="bar">bar2</li>
    <li data-dragtype="bar">bar3</li>
    <li data-dragtype="bar">bar4</li>
</ul>
```

And set the `limits` and `left` variables accordingly, without changing the code of the drop event handler. For example:

```
var limits = { test: 1, foo: 1, bar: 2}, left = 4;
```

Comment: Why a -1? This is a compact, expressive and flexible solution.